# Oitcontrol zoom?

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

Here the live preview: [Misc_control_orbit_demo](http://jsfiddle.net/user1/MqmTx1/)

I don't see any error in console but i can't zoom,

Can someone show me where i was wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try the [dev branch version](http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js). three.js r.66dev

Comment: Thanks for answer but that's orbitcontrol version not improve zoom on touch device like i want, it's just still the same, only Trackballcontrols do perfect on touch device

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong when you try to zoom with OrbitControls r.66 using your touch device?

Comment: Hi, it's hitch when zoomin, like when you press middle mouse and moving horizontal slowly, here the video i record compare Orbit and Trackball controls: [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0oDnsvQ0lw&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: OK, now I understand. Try using the three.js r.66 OrbitControls, remove `controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );` in the main program, and add `controls.update()` in the animation loop. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @WestLangley  remove "controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );" make controls stop working, [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/user972611/MqmTx/1/)

Comment: I bet you could have made this change yourself. http://jsfiddle.net/MqmTx/2/

Comment: Thanks, i'm new with this. The result's not improve on phone, still like before.

Comment: The demo works fine for me on iPhone (using CanvasRenderer, instead). Can you try your device with fewer pyramids ( 50 ), and also try CanvasRenderer to see if there are any other possible causes for the hitch you see?

Comment: I tried but nothing improve yet, every android phone i tried alway happen this hitch. I see that with Trackballcontrol, when i hold middle mouse and moving even horizontal or vertical, it's always compute zoom in or out belong to vertical, so on android i can slide two finger any direction it's still zoom correct. With Orbitcontrol, hold middle mouse and moving horizontal will make it zoom wrong, always zoom in with the 'hitch', so when slide  two finger horizontal on phone will happen that 'Hitch'. That's what i'm thinking.

Comment: Seem like i have to mod code between Trackball and OrbitControls again (i can't write by myself because i'm very new with coding), so if you have time, can you see what wrong with my code above? (or can you write the mod version for me). Thank you so much.

Comment: The controls are part of the examples, not the library, so each user is responsible for modifying it to their liking. Sorry, I can't help you modify the code as I have no way of testing it. However, it would be great if you could file a [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) on the three.js site, and include your video.